# Why not displayed inline elements? Bootstrap

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this site:

[link](http://www.les-toiles.co/account/cart/)

There you will find a section called your "You may be interested in…" with 3 or more pictures.

I want those pictures to be displayed in line and either the 3 columns.

I put a picture to understand better what they want.

http://i62.tinypic.com/25p7h9g.jpg

CODE PHP:

```
$classes = '';
if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 1 ) % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] || 1 == $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes = 'first';
if ( 0 == $woocommerce_loop['loop'] % $woocommerce_loop['columns'] )
    $classes = 'last';

$columns = 12/$woocommerce_loop['columns']
?>
<div <?php post_class(' shopcol col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 '.$classes.' '); ?>>
    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product-inner' ); ?>
</div>
```

So I tried to do the 3 columns to display images.

You please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? Or where's the live link? Can't find anything in the link you specified.

Comment: I searched through the site and couldnt find the problem area you mention

Comment: add 2-3 products in the cart and then click the "view cart" and you will see that I said section

Answer (score 0):

Remove this css from your page [located here](http://www.les-toiles.co/wp-content/themes/mix/css/woocommerce.css?ver=1.0) on line *5724*:

```
.products .first {
    clear: left;
}
```

I hope it will work fine.